# Cannot find image properties when uploading

Tags: files, media

I'm building an LXC based on an existing and working well website. I've checked that all settings where the same.
However, when I want to save a content after having uploaded an image on my LXC, I get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer
>   value.

I have thoroughly searched the web all the day to read every close topic but none gave me a suitable answer.

The fact is when the *Field SQL Storage* module try to get the properties of my image; it is unable to find its parameters, so the width and height properties are empty and the SQL query is crashing.

Why Drupal can't read my image properties and store them in database?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. There was missing packages in my server configuration...I needed to install those :

```
aptitude install php-apc php-pear php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt
```